# Perl disable shell access

Tags: perl, shell

Certain builtins like `system` and `exec` (as well as backticks) will use the shell (I think `sh` by default) if passed a single argument containing shell metacharacters. If I want to write a portable program that avoids making any assumptions about the underlying shell, is there a pragma or some other option I can use to either disable shell access or trigger a fatal error immediately?

Comment: You can avoid the Shell in `system` and `exec` using the syntax `system PROGRAM LIST`, see documentation for [system](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I write about this extensively in [Mastering Perl](http://www.masteringperl.org). The short answer is to use `system` in it's list form.

```
system '/path/to/command', @args;
```

This doesn't interpret any special characters in `@args`.

At the same time, you should enable taint checking to help catch bad data before you pass it to the system. See the [perlsec](http://perldoc.perl.org/persec.html) documentation for details.

Comment: Is there a way to upgrade use of `system` in non-list form to an error?

Answer (score 0):

There are limited options to do this, keep in mind that these are core routines and completely disabling them may have some unexpected consequences. You do have a few options.

**Override Locally**

You can override system and exec locally by using the `subs` pragma, this will only effect the package into which you have imported the sub routine:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use subs 'system';
sub system { die('Do not use system calls!!'); }
# .. more code here, note this will runn
my $out = system('ls -lah'); # I will die at this point, but not before
print $out;
```

**Override Globally**

To override globally, in the current perl process, you need to import your function into the CORE::GLOBAL pseudo-namespace at compile time:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

BEGIN {
    *CORE::GLOBAL::system = sub {
      die('Do not use system calls.');
    };

    *CORE::GLOBAL::exec = sub {
      die('Do not use exec.');
    };

    *CORE::GLOBAL::readpipe = sub {
      die('Do not use back ticks.');
    };
}

#...
my $out = system('ls -lah'); # I will die at this point, but not before
print $out;
```

**Prevent anything form running if in source**

If you want to prevent any code running before getting to a system call you can include the following, note this is fairly loose in it's matching, I've written it to be easy to modify or update:

```
package Acme::Noshell;

open 0 or print "Can't execute '$0'\n" and exit;
my $source = join "", <0>;

die("Found back ticks in '$0'") if($source =~ m/^.*[^#].*\`/g);
die("Found 'exec' in '$0'") if($source =~ / exec\W/g);
die("Found 'system' in '$0'") if($source =~ / system\W/g);

1;
```

Which can be used as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Acme::Noshell;

print "I wont print because of the call below";
my $out = system('ls -lah');
```